# Modifying existing modules with archetype update

Tags: maven, jar, pojo

I have a project which was designed using a custom archetype to build modules under parent project as follows -

[image: Module Structure]

---

***Details*** - The archetype implements a `<configuration>` in the `<build>` phase with a `<mainClass>` let's say `Generator` that builds the classes under the `pojos` and `service` packages into a single target folder and hence enabling to create the final JAR for the `user` module as `user-1.0.0.jar`

---

There's some requirement in terms of separately exposing the `pojos` without the intervention of `service` code that has left me brainstorming -

1. Is there a way to modify the existing archetype or module structure to get two separate JARs for the packages `pojos` and `service` as `user-pojos-1.0.0.jar` and `user-service-1.0.0.jar`?

One way I possibly know is to move the code in two different module and building their jars but then for multiple existing modules under the parent and a thought over the same name modules under the parent, wouldn't be preferable.

2. Is there a way to modify the currently obtained `user-1.0.0.jar` created and separate out it into the two JARs required same as above?

Comment: Use a multi-module Maven project, this is the only solution to your problem. A Maven project has a single, and only single, main artifact, not two.

Comment: @Tunaki If I am not getting you wrong here, you meant creating multi-module project with somthing like a parent pom `user` and with sub-module as `pojos`, and `service`?